# Register all implementation of type T interface in .NET core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have an interface

```
public interface IEvent { }
```

An Event class

```
public class ContactEvent : IEvent { }
```

Two Event Handlers classes

```
public class ContactCreateHandler : IEventHandler<ContactEvent> { }
public class ContactUpdateHandler : IEventHandler<ContactEvent> { }
```

In .NET 4.5 this was possible using Autofac

```
var assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()
            .Cast<Assembly>()
            .ToArray()

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
.AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IEventHandler<>)).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();
```

And then I would get the list of classes based on the type T

```
var handlerList = _container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IEventHandler<T>>>();
```

How to do this in .NET Core

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor).  With that, you can then scan and assign the handlers like this:

```
// Automatically discover and register all message handlers...
services.Scan(
    x =>
        {
            var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
            var referencedAssemblies = entryAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies().Select(Assembly.Load);
            var assemblies = new List<Assembly> { entryAssembly }.Concat(referencedAssemblies);

            x.FromAssemblies(assemblies)
                .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo(typeof(IEventHandler<>)))
                    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                    .WithScopedLifetime();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with Scrutor:

All classes register by namespace.In this code:

IEmailSenderService > namespace = "Identity.Core.Services"

IMailInfoFactory > namespace = "Identity.Core.Factories"

```
services.Scan(
                x =>
                {
                    var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
                    var assemblies = entryAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies().Select(Assembly.Load);

                    x.FromAssemblies(assemblies)
                    .AddClasses(classes => classes.InNamespaceOf(typeof(IEmailSenderService)))
                    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                    .WithScopedLifetime()
                    .AddClasses(classes => classes.InNamespaceOf(typeof(IMailInfoFactory)))
                    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                    .WithScopedLifetime();
                });
```

or if you want to register all class in assembly:

```
services.Scan(
               x =>
               {
                   x.FromAssembliesOf(typeof(IEmailSenderService))
                   .AddClasses()
                   .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                   .WithScopedLifetime();
               });
```